# Python Tkinter text entry box to insert data to SQL Server

Tags: python, sql-server, tkinter, exception, sql-insert

I have created a small python tkinter program designed to have a user write data into text entry boxes in the app then insert this data into a MS SQL server database.  When clicking the insert button I am getting the following error message, stopping the app from insert the code into SQL.

> cursor.execute("INSERT INTO TEST_DISA_MAIN_TABLE VALUES (:DENSITY_VALUE, :DATE, :TIME, :CHART_VALUE)",
> pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('The SQL contains 0 parameter markers, but 1 parameters were supplied', 'HY000')*

This is my code for the python insert function:

```
def insertvalue():
    # Create a database or connect to one
    conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                  'Server=MON-SQL-02;'
                  'Database=ENVIRONMENTAL;'
                  'Trusted_Connection=yes;')
    # Create cursor
    cursor = conn.cursor()

    # Insert into table
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO TEST_DISA_MAIN_TABLE VALUES (:DENSITY_VALUE, :DATE, :TIME, :CHART_VALUE)",
            {
                'DENSITY_VALUE': DENSITY_VALUE.get(),
                'DATE': DATE.get(),
                'TIME': TIME.get(),
                'CHART_VALUE': CHART_VALUE.get(),
            })

    # Commit changes
    conn.commit()
    #Close Connection
    conn.close()

    # Clear the text boxes
    DENSITY_VALUE.delete(0, END)
    DATE.delete(0, END)
    TIME.delete(0, END)
    CHART_VALUE.delete(0, END)

#Create text boxes
DENSITY_VALUE = Entry(root, width=30)
DENSITY_VALUE.grid(row=2, column=1)
DATE = Entry(root, width=30)
DATE.grid(row=3, column=1)
TIME = Entry(root, width=30)
TIME.grid(row=4, column=1)
CHART_VALUE = Entry(root, width=30)
CHART_VALUE.grid(row=5, column=1)

#Create Text box labels
DENSITY_VALUE_Label = Label(root, text="Density Value")
DENSITY_VALUE_Label.grid(row=2, column=0)
DATE_Label = Label(root, text="Date")
DATE_Label.grid(row=3, column=0)
TIME_Label = Label(root, text="Time")
TIME_Label.grid(row=4, column=0)
CHART_VALUE_Label = Label(root, text="Chart Value")
CHART_VALUE_Label.grid(row=5, column=0)

button = Button(root, text = "Show All Values", command = showvalues)
button.grid(row=0, column=0)

button = Button(root, text = "Insert Values", command = insertvalue)
button.grid(row=1, column=0)

#Commit changes
conn.commit()

# Close connection
conn.close()

root.mainloop()
```

I used this format to insert data into a sqlite3 db, but the same format is not working when inserting into a SQL Server database.  I have tested the connection to the SQL server and can display values in the app so that part works correctly.

Comment: The parameter markers for PyODBC are question marks (`?`). You can see an [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/python/pyodbc/step-3-proof-of-concept-connecting-to-sql-using-pyodbc?view=sql-server-ver16#insert-a-row) in the documentation on how to send parameters to your query.

Comment: Also you should specify the columns you are inserting into `INSERT INTO TEST_DISA_MAIN_TABLE (Col1, Col2...) VALUES (...`